Borrar un objeto de un ArrayList buscado por nombre
Buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio de introducir datos, mostrar, busca, borrar y modificar los datos que se encuentra en el fichero liga.dat. Y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de borrar, me dice que no lo encuentra y me borra todos los datos guardados aqui proporciono el metodo.
private static void opcion5(File fichero, String equipo) {
    try{
        ArrayList<Equipos>e=new ArrayList<>();
        FileOutputStream escribir=new FileOutputStream(fichero);
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(escribir);
        FileInputStream leer=new FileInputStream(fichero);
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(leer);
        while(leer.available()>0) {
            Equipos eq=(Equipos)ois.readObject();
            e.add(eq);
        }
        leer.close();
        ois.close();
        for(Equipos es:e) {
            if (es.getNombreEquipo().equals(equipo)) {
                e.remove(es);
                System.out.println("Se ha eliminado correctamente");
            }
        }
        
        
        
        for(Equipos es:e) {
            oos.writeObject(es);
        }
        oos.close();
        escribir.close();
        
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) { cnf.printStackTrace(); }
}

El resultado tendria que ser que me borra solo el que introduzco me podrian ayudar
El codigo que ahora utilizo este para sobreescribir el antiguo
private static void opcion5(File fichero, String equipo) {
        File original=fichero;
        File temporal=new File (fichero+".dat");
        boolean encontrado=false;
        try {
            FileOutputStream escribir=new FileOutputStream(fichero);
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(escribir);
            FileInputStream leer=new FileInputStream(fichero);
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(leer);
            Equipos equipos=(Equipos)ois.readObject();
            while(equipos!=null) {
                if (equipos.getNombreEquipo().equals(equipo)) {
                    encontrado=true;
                }
                if(!equipos.getNombreEquipo().equals(equipo)) {
                    oos.writeObject(equipos);
                }
                equipos=(Equipos)ois.readObject();
            }
            oos.close();
            ois.close();
            leer.close();
            escribir.close();
            
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) { 
            cnf.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        if (encontrado) {
            System.out.println("EL equipos " + equipo + "se ha borrado");
        }
        original.delete();
        temporal.renameTo(original);    
    }
}

pero lo dicho todavia no me funciona

Aquí respondo a una pregunta muy, muy parecida a la tuya. Creo que uno de los problemas que tienes es leer y escribir en el mismo fichero. Deberías escribir en uno temporal y luego renombrarlo. Échale un ojo al enlace y aplica esa y otras optimizaciones como el try-catch-with-resources.

He mirado el codigo que me dejaste  lo he modificado para que asi sea con los daos que yo tengo pero sigue si funcionar me sale error a la hora de leer los objetos

error.. que error... como podemos saber de que error hablas?

java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3232)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:540)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:498)
at Ejercicio15.opcion5(Ejercicio15.java:181)
at Ejercicio15.main(Ejercicio15.java:40)

Sí, esa excepción sale cuando se llega al final del fichero. En mi código se captura pero esa parte no la has tenido en cuenta.

Pude reproducir 2 problemas basandome en el primer bloque de codigo que compartes.
El primero efectivamente trunca el archivo porque para este caso en concreto se debe leer el contenido luego cerrar el FileInputStream y por ultimo sí proceder con la operacion de escritura.
El segundo se trató de una ConcurrentModificationException al tratar de borrar un elemento de una lista en la cual se está iterando.
De tal manera que:
//Primero la operacion de lectura
ArrayList<Equipos>e=new ArrayList<>();
FileInputStream leer=new FileInputStream(fichero);
ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(leer);
while(leer.available()>0) {
    Equipos eq=(Equipos)ois.readObject();
    e.add(eq);
}
leer.close();
ois.close();

/*Despues se evita la ConcurrentModificationException valiendose de una
  lista que almacenara el o los datos a eliminar, de ese modo no eliminara
  al tiempo que iterara la misma lista*/
ArrayList<Equipos>rm=new ArrayList<>();
for(Equipos es:e) {
    if (es.getNombreEquipo().equalsIgnoreCase(equipo)) {
        //e.remove(es);
        rm.add(es);
        System.out.println("Se ha eliminado correctamente");
    }
}
e.removeAll(rm);

/*Por ultimo la operacion de escritura.
  Notese que las instancias ahora estan despues de cerrar los streams
  de lectura, por eso antes dejaba el archivo truncado o vacio*/
FileOutputStream escribir=new FileOutputStream(fichero);
ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(escribir);
for(Equipos es:e) {
    oos.writeObject(es);
}
oos.close();
escribir.close();

